# Set first child element to inactive state

Tags: jquery

Hi have this code and I whant to have the first accordion to be closed. Any whints on how to make it work?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.accordion .container').hide();
jQuery('.accordion .trigger:first-child').addClass('active').next().show();

jQuery('.accordion .trigger').click(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        jQuery(this).parent().find(".trigger").removeClass('active').next().slideUp('fast');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('fast');
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Please explain better - tell us what you want to happen, and what *is* happening, and show us some html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
jQuery('.accordion .trigger:first-child').addClass('active').next().show();
```

To:

```
jQuery('.accordion .trigger').first().removeClass('active').hide().next().addClass('active').show();
```

Comment: @Archer I removed the `.next()`. Didn't see?

Comment: This isn't working because the first according this is open and I need them all to be closed opening just when the user select the that wishes to see

Comment: sorry... It does work! The problem was that I have to make the changes on two files...